# UIButton only shows tintColor on longPress

Tags: ios, uibutton

UIBarButtonItem changes its tintColor immediately on touchDown, but UIButton seems to wait for longPress before showing it's highlighted color...

What is the correct way to change a button's highlight color immediately on touchDown?

Comment: It's anywhere I use a UIButton.

Comment: yeah, It is same to me......